# POST vars suddenly not working through jQuery based AJAX calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

This has been happening since I migrated servers (upgraded to a dedicated server)

The AJAX calls, based on jQuery, were working fine for months (if not years) and suddenly they ALL stopped working, across all my accounts. You can imagine my panic.

The removefile function looks like this:

```
 function removefile(filename,folder,targetdiv) { // universal AJAX file removal function. folder MUST include '/' at the beginning for calls. 
    $.post('ajax_removefile.php', {folder:folder, filename:filename },
        function(data){
            if(data=='1') {
            $('#'+targetdiv).html(filename+' has been successfully removed.');
            }
            else if(data=='0') {
            $('#'+targetdiv).html(filename+' is already removed - nothing more to remove.');
            }
        });
}
```

But for some reason, even though Firebug shows a successful registration of the POSt vars being sent, the php file returns completely empty POSt vars. `print_r($_POST)` or `print_r($_REQUEST)` returns empty arrays in both cases. If I change the method to a GET mechanism it works - but I'd like to keep it at a POST variable.

Comment: How strange. It seems to me that it's more likely to be a problem with your Apache or PHP configuration if it's after a migration to a new server...

Comment: I know! But the server admins at inmotionhosting.com are useless at the moment.

Comment: Had a quick search and I can't find anything that would be responsible for this :S

Comment: Well, at least I can tell you I don't think there's anything wrong with your Post request.

Comment: try to extract version informations on the Apache and PHP version, especially versions of modules in apache (from http response headers, server signature on 404 or phpinfo, maybe an old version of mod_security for example (where chunked request bodies were consider bad)

Comment: @jeffkee, have you recently updated the jquery core file or are you using a CDN to the latest jquery? I have seen sudden errors in my jquery when the CDN to the latest that I was using changed. You could try rolling back to a previous version of jquery to see if that changes anything and then work forward from there.

Comment: Acutally I was already on 1.3.2 so I upgraded to 1.6.x to make sure.

Comment: http://picnetbc.sonikastudios.com/admin/phpinfo.php  will show PHP info.. I couldn't spot anything out of the ordinary but I don't understand most of the directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, the issue was due to a post_max_size that was set too high. Yes, too high. I had to drop it down to what's written in the core php.ini file. I had it set to 20000M across different accounts to just make sure it's practically unlimited, so I had to drop that to 128M (as per the core php.ini max) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can see the raw incoming request in PHP:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
var(dump($input);
```

This will prove that the POST data arrived to PHP or that it was filtered on its way.

Don't forget to set the error_reporting to its max. If you don't want to set this in your php.ini, you can use `ini_set()` at the beginning of your PHP source, or a .htaccess with `php_value` (and a integer value).

You probably have a problem with your php.ini. I'm not positive about it, but it may be because your value of post_max_size is far above the 32 bits max integer. Though your PHP seems to be on a 64 bits server, this could be the source of the problem. I suggest you change it from 200000M to 1G. To change this, you can use a .htaccess as above, but then check its effectiveness with `ini_get()`.

It could also be wrong HTTP headers in your AJAX queries, but that seems less likely as nothing changed on this side before the bug appeared.

Comment: var(dump($input); is returning an error even after I add the missing ) at the end.

Comment: OK Changed it to var_dump after doing a quick lookup.. and here's what I got: string(49) "folder=..%2Fcalendars%2F8&filename=attachment.pdf"   so the POSt vars are working. Even Firebug clearly defines it as a POST var.. not a GET var. But when I try to use $_POST it returns null values..

Comment: Probably not the wrong headers, as I'm using a standard jQuery call, not something I made.